# Unix commands and regex to find the total counts for different criteria

Tags: regex, unix

I am a new to unix commands and regex. I applied the following commands to   [this English corpus](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mp3hdro5bka5zhq/testFile.txt?dl=0) and I am not sure about them.

a. Count the total number of words (tokens) : I got 2685545

```
wc -w  testFile.txt
```

b. Count the total number of unique words (types).   I wrote two different command, and not sure which one is correct. The number of types: 657286 or 74066

```
cat  testFile.txt |perl -pe 's/\s/\n/g;' |sort  |uniq -c   

or 

cat  testFile.txt |perl -pe 's/\s/\n/g;' |sort |uniq -c |wc -w
```

c. Count the total number of unique words ignoring capitalization. I got 1910951

```
cat testFile.txt |perl -pe 's/[a-z]\w+/\n/g;' |sort |uniq -c
```

d. Count the total number of pure digits tokens.

```
cat  testFile.txt |perl -pe 's/\s/\n/g;' |grep '[0-9]{1,}' |sort |uniq -c |wc -w
```

e. Count the total number of digits with non-word characters with them (e.g. 8,000.00) I got 18666230

```
wc -c  testFile.txt |perl -pe ’s/[0-9]{1,}\W+[0-9]{1,}\W+[0-9]
{1,}/\n/g;’
```

f. Count the total number of words starting with capital letters. I got 1048

```
cat  testFile.txt |perl -pe 's/[A-Z]\w+/\n/g;' |egrep '[A-Z]\w+' |wc -w
```

g. What are the top 15 most common first words of sentences

```
cat testFile.txt |perl -pe 's/\s/\n/g;' |sort |uniq -c |sort -nr 
|head -15
```

h. What are the top most common capitalized words (that are not sentence initial).

```
perl -nE 'say $1 while /(\w*[A-Z]+\w*)/g' testFile.txt
```

I got this [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt4Up.png) (screenshot is part of the out put):

i. Count all occurrences of Roman numerals 2684068

```
cat  testFile.txt |egrep -i '[IX|IV|V?I{1,3}]' |wc -w
```

Your help will be very appreciated!

Comment: There is a problem with the link to the file I think

Comment: Don't hide essential information behind a link. Include everything relevant in the question itself.

Comment: the link is a long text file. it's a corpus which I can't copied here :/

Comment: 'What is a word'? Is `RESOLUTION 55/100` one word ('RESOLUTION'), two words ('RESOLUTION', '55/100') or three words  ('RESOLUTION', '55','100')? How you count is interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Lets just take the first few line of the text you posted:

```
$ cat file.txt
RESOLUTION 55/100 
Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on the recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1, para. 94), by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as follows: 
55/100. Respect for the right to universal freedom of travel and the vital importance of family reunification 
The General Assembly, 
Reaffirming that all human rights and fundamental freedoms are universal, indivisible, interdependent and interrelated, 
Recalling the provisions of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, as well as article 12 of the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights, 
Stressing that, as stated in the Programme of Action of the International Conference on Population and Development, family reunification of documented migrants is an important factor in international migration and that remittances by documented migrants to their countries of origin often constitute a very important source of foreign exchange and are instrumental in improving the well-being of relatives left behind, 
Recalling its resolution 54/169 of 17 December 1999, 
1. Once again calls upon all States to guarantee the universally recognized freedom of travel to all foreign nationals legally residing in their territory; 
2. Reaffirms that all Governments, in particular those of receiving countries, must recognize the vital importance of family reunification and promote its incorporation into national legislation in order to ensure protection of the unity of families of documented migrants; 
3. Calls upon all States to allow, in conformity with international legislation, the free flow of financial remittances by foreign nationals residing in their territory to their relatives in the country of origin; 
4. Also calls upon all States to refrain from enacting, and to repeal if it already exists, legislation intended as a coercive measure that discriminates against individuals or groups of legal migrants by adversely affecting family reunification and the right to send financial remittance to relatives in the country of origin; 
5. Decides to continue its consideration of this question at its fifty-seventh session under the item entitled "Human rights questions".
```

The first thing to do is define 'what is a word'?

1. `RESOLUTION` clearly is; what about `55/100`?
2. What about things in quotes or parenthesis?
3. What about 'big' 'Big' 'Big!' 'Big?' 'Big.'? Are those all the same word or four different words? `wc` counts those as four different words.

Assuming you mean that a 'word' is the lowercase version stripped of all non word characters, you can use a regex to find all words and then lower case so that they compare the same.

In Perl, you can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jTW4qh/1/) `/\b(\p{L}+)/` to find words.

```
$ perl -lne 'while (/\b(\p{L}+)/g) {$h{lc($1)}++;} END{foreach (sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys(%h)) {print "$_: $h{$_}"}}' file.txt
of: 25
the: 20
to: 13
and: 11
in: 10
all: 6
that: 5
as: 5
migrants: 4
reunification: 4
family: 4
their: 4
its: 4
by: 4
rights: 4
on: 4
international: 4
...
```

Adding unique word counts and total word counts against your file, I get:

```
$ perl -lne 'while (/\b(\p{L}+)/g) {$h{lc($1)}++;} 
                  END{print "unique words: ".scalar keys %h; 
                  foreach (values %h) { $s+=$_ }
                  print "total words: $s";
                  foreach (sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys(%h)) {print "$_: $h{$_}"}}' testFile.txt | head
unique words: 11263
total words: 2616047
the: 272618
of: 176015
and: 138295
to: 101670
in: 67440
on: 36025
for: 32558
a: 24742
```